# What can cause DCLUSR.$$$ access denied error whilst installing a user defined component

Tags: delphi, vcl

I have found the component `TColorbutton` and am trying to install it in Delphi 10.4.2. I know that is currently embedded in FMX, but I want it available in VCL. However, the installation fails:

> Failed to save project "c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\21.0\lib\win32\release \dclusr.dproj". The following error occurred while saving: Cannot create file "c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\21.0\lib\win32\release\dclusr.$$$"

What can I do to get it installed? Or, is there a way to use the FMX version within VCL?

Answer (score 3):

The installation fails because you are trying to install the component while its unit is under the `C:\Program Files (x86)` folder. Since this folder is one of the protected system folders, Windows prevents Delphi from creating necessary files during compilation.

You should move the component File to a non-protected folder, like `C:\Users\<YourUsername>\Documents\Embarcadero` before you try to install it. This way, Delphi won't be blocked by Windows while compiling the needed component package.

Comment: thanks for answering. But I had the unit of the component already located in C:\APPS of in a subdirectory thereof. All paths that Delphi accesses come as standard after the installation of version 10.4.2, and I checked it to misfunction the same on my other PC. I even renamed the unit, to make sure that it was not caused by any interaction with the FMX.TColorbutton version. Hope you can provide me another clue. Perhaps I should send you the environment path list, but I see no way to export it. Do you?

Comment: The error clearly states that Delphi is trying to build your project at `c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\21.0\lib\win32\release \dclusr.dproj`. So something is at that location. All design time components gets built into packages. So I'm guessing you have chosen your package to be created at this folder. NOTE: While most packages that ship with Delphi are actually located at `c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\21.0\lib` it is not necessary that every package is located in that folder. In fact you can have your component package located anywhere.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I have still no idea what to do to get it right. There only is a unit with a component TColorbutton that I want to install. The location is in C\Apps and there is nothing within the unit that tells where to install. The directory "c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\21.0\lib\win32\release" comes out of the blue after a fresh installation of Delphi. What can I do to direct the "dclusr-files" to a valid location? Please help.

Comment: @JGMS I never mess around with the `dclusr` package. Whenever I want to install custom components, I always create new packages for them, in my own folders.

Comment: @Silverwarior, I finally managed to install the component after running Delphi as administrator. Kind of weird. I still hope anybody can give me a hint how to set things back to normal. Now I see the remark from Remy: I will follow that route in future.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're trying to "extract" a component from the FMX lib and "move it over" to the VCL lib. DO NOT DO THAT!!! If you THINK you got it to work, you probably hosed-up your installation.

You didn't say what library you installed this into, but you should always install your own components into your own component library. I use one that I call "AddOns". Some people use their name. If you try to install it into one of the system libs, you're going to find it impossible to install Delphi updates as well as any libraries that depend on those components. NEVER UPDATE DELPHI COMPONENT LIBRARIES!!! (Yes, you CAN, but just DON'T!)

VCL and FMX use totally different approaches to writing to the screen (among other things), which is why they are separate libraries. FMX has a layer between the component and the platform's "screen" (OpenGL I believe), while VCL calls the Windows API directly.

If there's stuff in FMX that you'd like to see in VCL, then look for a VCL-specific component that does what you want. Or build your own that derives from an existing one.

Search Google for TColorButton and you'll find several references to things you can use. There are some on Torry's.

There's an article on it in the newer about.com site (ThoughtCo.com) but I couldn't find a link there to the source code.

Google is your friend. Try this:

https://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/en/showcode.php?id=1100

Comment: You surely convinced me not to mix FMX and VCL code. But so far I didn't. Like you couldn't, neither I could find the link to the code of Tcolourbutton in the site of ThoughtCo.com. But I had it use some years ago and found it on a backup disk. It works OK, though it is installed in a system package rather than in one of my own. But next time I know better. Thank you.

Comment: Although the installation of TColorButton seemed successful at first glance, it appears to make Checkbox components in the active tabsheet invisible (or at least assigns the background color to the caption of the checkbox). Whenever I click on a checkbox its caption disappears. So weird! By the way, the link that you gave in your previous comment did not work, so there were no 'helpful references' to be checked. Any suggestion what is going on?

Comment: I simply searched Google for a minute or so and found something, but I guess it's gone now, so I removed the link from above. You seem to be trying to justify your approach when several of us have said it's not a viable approach. There's plenty of stuff on this topic around the interwebs that explain the underlying problem you need to address. Please try leveraging this info or finding the source for this component somewhere to play with. Google shows an article with source as the 6th link for me. What do you find?

Comment: I found colorbutton.pas in "www.swissdelpicenter.ch" and one from "delphi.about.com'. They both work and I have installed them in private packages. The installation of the components is no longer a problem. However, when using either one of the TColorbuttons (one of them installed of course) their codes both interfere with the behaviour of checkbox captions in the same application. Apparently, the ColorButton canvas-write code is not compatible with Windows 10. When I use style 'Windows' there is no problem, but who wants that appearance nowadays? I have no idea to solve this. Do you?

Comment: Great to hear you found one that works! Did you remove the one from the library you installed earlier? Also, what style are you using that does cause the problem?